# how to display more than 5 digit in markerview

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to display 7 digit data in mpandroidchart markerview, but it only show 5 digit. Here is my code. I've try to set ellipsize of my textview to none, but still not works. When I log the entry, it show 7 digit, but in my markerview it only show 5 digit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/bg_marker_view">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_xs"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/padding_xs"
    android:tag="customMarker"
    android:text="marker"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
</RelativeLayout>


class CustomMarkerView(context: Context?, layoutResource: Int) :
MarkerView(context, layoutResource) {
private val tvContent: TextView = findViewWithTag("customMarker")

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
override fun refreshContent(
    e: Entry,
    highlight: Highlight
) {
    // set the entry-value as the display text
    tvContent.text = e.y.toString().replace("000000.0", " juta")
    Log.d("refreshContent", e.toString())
}

override fun getOffset(): MPPointF? {
    val x = -(width / 2).toFloat()
    return MPPointF(getX(), (-height + (-10)).toFloat())
}
}
```

Comment: Better use `AutoSizing` for text view . See [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

Comment: @ADM `AutoSizing` is not works.

Comment: Can you try a smaller Text Size and see if it works? i have not used  `mpandroidchart` but if its not working with Small text Size then i think the library rounding of the data . Debug the code .

Comment: i've try a smaller textsize, the text is smaller, but it still cant show more than 5 character